# How can I place iOS Simulator windows programmatically at launch?

Tags: ios, position, window

I need to run several iOS simulators to run tests in parallel. I can do this with open -n, but the windows all open on top of each other so it only looks like one is running, which is confusing.

I could use something like this Applescript to spread them out:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set x to 0
    repeat with proc in (application processes whose name is "Simulator")
        tell proc to repeat with wind in windows
            set the position of wind to {x, x}
            set x to x + 100
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

but that means they move around after they've appeared, and I have to run it each time a new window appears, which means any placement already imposed on the old windows is lost, annoying anyone trying to do desktop admin, and I'm really not inclined to write more Applescript to track which windows it's moved and which ones it hasn't.

Is there a plist (ideally a per-image plist) I can edit before launch, to position the window? I tried

```
 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set SimulatorWindowCenterX 100" \
       ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist
```

to no avail.